# Conditional forms with jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this multiuse script:

```
<script>
$( document ).bind( "pageinit", function( event, data ) {
    $("#ppreg").hide();
    $("#smsreg").hide();
    $("#UserName").hide();
    $(".group1").hide();
    $(".group2").hide();
    $(".group0").hide();

$('#selectcode').change(function() {
      var regtype = $("#selectcode option:selected").val();
        if (regtype == "@") {
          $("#ppreg").show();
          $("#smsreg").hide();
          $("#UserName").show();
          $(".group1").show();
          $(".group2").hide();
          $(".group0").show();          
        } else {
          $("#ppreg").hide();
          $("#smsreg").show();
          $("#UserName").show();
      $(".group2").show();
          $(".group1").hide();
          $(".group0").show();  
       }
 });
});
    </script>
```

Scope 1: show two different label based on selected value
Scope 2: show all other fileds after the countrycode selection

In this form it runs fine:

```
 <label for="selectcode" class="select">LABEL"; 
 <select name="countrycode" id="selectcode" data-native-menu=\"true">
<option value="@">email (email field)</option>
    <option value="+39" >SMS:(+39)</option>
    </select>
<fieldset data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d" data-collapsed="false">"
    <legend>"._LOGIN."</legend>"

<div class="group0>"

<label for="UserName" id="smsreg" >Username1</label>
     <label for="UserName" id="ppreg" >Username 2</label>
     ---- A
    <input title="TITLE" type="text" name="UserName" value="" class="required"  id="UserName" data-clear-btn="true"  />"
     ----- //A
   <div class="group0">
   <label class="group0" for="Password">Password:</label>
   <input class="group0" type="password" name="Password"   value="" id="Password" data-clear-btn="true"  placeholder="Password" /> 
.. MORE FIELDS ..
<button id="login" type="submit" value="validate!" data-theme="b">LOGIN</button> 
   </div>
```

but  if I change the above html (A) in order to get two different input type fields for UserName (tel or email), the layout looks fine but the form sents a null value for UserName when I select the first option (tel):

```
     ----- A1
    <div class="group2">
    <input title="TITLE1" type="tel" name="UserName" value="" class="required group2"  id="UserName" data-clear-btn="true"  />"
    </div>
    <div class="group1">
    <input title="TITLE2" type="email" name="UserName" value="" class="required group1"  id="UserName" data-clear-btn="true"  />
   </div>
   ------- // A1
```

The reason is clear, the question is: anyone could suggest me how avoids the issue?

Comment: Each form control should have a unique name attribute.

Comment: here the solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936612/how-to-change-input-type-on-selection-with-jquery-mobile

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the same id in the same page.
Use the same class with a different id for the two types.

For example

```
<div class="group2">
    <input title="TITLE1" type="tel" name="UserName" value="" class="username required group2"  id="UserNameTel" data-clear-btn="true"  />"
    </div>
    <div class="group1">
    <input title="TITLE2" type="email" name="UserName" value="" class="username required group1"  id="UserNameMail" data-clear-btn="true"  />
   </div>
```

and choose different selector in jquery script.

Comment: Looks like that changing id and using different selector doesn't solve. 
The UserName value is always Null for the first ones (type="tel").
Would be possible to change only the "type value" in the input element?

Comment: To me is quite normal, you should handle this on the submit moment. Try to create a fiddle if you want.

Comment: I was thinking at something like this with only one input element:     $("#UserName").setAttribute('type','email');
$("#UserName").setAttribute('type','tel');

Comment: Here the solution -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936612/how-to-change-input-type-on-selection-with-jquery-mobile